# Adding Different Markers to Different Lines in Matplotlib Charts/Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a chart of the performance of different optimisations/C flags for the Intel-icc compiler with increasing system size. There are 4 in total but it can be hard to see each one of them on the chart despite the different colours. The best way of distinguishing them will be to add a different marker to each line. However, this is where I'm stuck. Although I can use 1 marker, therefore all lines will have the same marker; not much use.

What works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot.line(marker = 'x')
plt.xlabel('System Size')
plt.ylabel('Updated Cells')
```

Thats fine. [image]

So I guess the problem I've got is associating a different marker/symbol to each line.

Any help/direction appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a quick loop and plot each column separately:

```
for m, col in zip('xosd', df):
    df[col].plot(marker=m)
    
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice. Cheers for that